# From console applications to .NET Windows form

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have been programming some console applications for a while now and I would like to throw myself into Visual C++ Windows form programming.

I'd like to say I was using another IDE before, devc++ and now I am kinda finding myself lost in this whole new .NET world.

My question is where could I find any material specific to my situation? Jumping from console applications to windows form ones? Any tutorial / Guide someone could address me to?

I am so thankful!

Comment: Although completely possible, I would personally recommend using C# or VB.NET for WinForms applications. C++/CLI is not necessarily geared towards writting 100% managed code (again... possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you re beginner to windows UI application (C++). there are three kind of programming types you have to study.

1. Windows API applications (without MFC)
2. MCF without CLR support (without .NET framework)
3. CLR support applications (with .NET framework )

First find what are the pros and cons of those.
Then I purpose you to start Win32 programming with this tutorial. 
http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/start.html